# SQL schema design: many-to-many relationship trouble while fetching data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-design

I'm maintaining one e-commerce website focusing on selling clothing(in LAMP).

The most important table of database is the clothing table.

This table has fields like 'clothing name', 'clothing type', 'clothing style'

there are some styles representing in numbers.

e.g,

> 1 = fashion 2 = cute 3 = sexy 4 = casual .. etc

every clothing can have multiple styles (separated by comma), so rows may look like this:

```
'clothing_name' 'clothing_style'
Nice T-shirt      1,3,11,15
Old Jeans         1,2,8
Adida T-shirt     3,4,7
Nike T-shirt      3,4,7
```

every time I want to display the styles of one clothing, i do something like this:

```
<?php
      /* 
       * $clothing['style'] is not usable
       * so transform it into array first
       */
      $style_numbers = explode(",", $clothing['style']);
      $clothing['style_numbers'] = array();
      if (!empty($clothing['style'])){
          foreach ($style_numbers as $style_number){
            $clothing['style_numbers'][] = (int) $style_number;
          }        
      }

      // and then mapping the numbers into its corresponding names
?>
```

this way, i got one array of styles and i can display style names with this.

everything is fine until i want to implement 'similar clothing' feature

i don't know how to set the SQL clause for even getting all 'cute' clothing (style code for cute is 2)

i have two questions

1. how could I implement 'similar clothing' feature in this situation ?
2. implementing many-to-many relationship this way (storing all value in one field separated by commas) is a bad practice? if so, what's the better solution?

Im appreciate for any advices.

Thank you very much and im sorry for my poor English.

Comment: 1. See 2. 2. This IS bad practice. See normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET` to check to see if a piece of clothing has a certain style:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('2',clothing_style) FROM clothing;
```

This will produce `0` for any pieces of clothing without style 2.

The usual schema for this would be to have three tables. Your existing clothing table:

```
clothing
id          clothing_name
```

A new clothing_style table:

```
clothing_style
id          style_name
```

And a table linking the two:

```
clothing_clothing_style
clothing_id  clothing_style_id
```

This allows adding styles more easily since the code doesn't need to know the mapping between styles and names since this is stored in the database.

Some examples:

```
-- Get all funny clothing
SELECT c.* FROM clothing c
INNER JOIN clothing_clothing_style ccs ON (ccs.clothing_id = c.id)
INNER JOIN clothing_style cs ON (ccs.clothing_style_id = cs.id AND cs.style_name = 'Funny');

-- Get list of clothing and comma separated list of styles
SELECT c.*,GROUP_CONCAT(cs.name) FROM clothing c
INNER JOIN clothing_clothing_style ccs ON (ccs.clothing_id = c.id)
INNER JOIN clothing_style cs ON (ccs.clothing_style_id = cs.id)
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: FIND_IN_SET is exactly what i need for now. thank you very much. you really help me with my two questions :D

Comment: btw, since the existence of FIND_IN_SET, maybe it's not really BAD PRACTICE to store strings inform of array in columns? :)

Comment: @尤川豪 I wouldn't say it was good practice because there is a method which helps. If the clothing styles are unlikely to change there's probably no harm in using `FIND_IN_SET` however.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is that Don't Store Strings inform of array in any column of table.Use multiple rows for this. It increase no of rows but makes your work easier When you are using complax queries
something like that

```
'clothing_name' 'clothing_style'
 Nice T-shirt      1
 Nice T-shirt      3
 Nice T-shirt      11
 Nice T-shirt      15
 Old Jeans         1
 Old Jeans         2
 Old Jeans         8
```

Answer (score 1):

1. For getting all cute clothes do a query like this:

   SELECT * 
   FROM clothes
   WHERE clothing_style LIKE '%2%'
2. you are right: using a column for more then one value isnt so good - my suggestion:

you already have your 'clothing' table - i suppose it has an id. remove the 
clothing_style column and put it into an own table where you store each style an an own row:

```
table clothing:
clothing_id clothing_name
1 Nice T-shirt
2 Old Jeans
3 Adida T-shirt
4 Nike T-shirt

table clothing_styles
clothing_id clothing_style
1 1
1 3
1 11
1 15
2 1
2 2
2 8
3 3
3 4
3 7
4 3
4 4
4 7
```

Comment: Using `clothing_style LIKE '%2%'` will also give clothes that have style `12`.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE `clothing` (
    `cloth_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cloth_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cloth_styles` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`cloth_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `clothing` (`cloth_name`, `cloth_styles`) VALUES ('jeans', '2,3,4');
INSERT INTO `clothing` (`cloth_name`, `cloth_styles`) VALUES ('hat', '2');
INSERT INTO `clothing` (`cloth_name`, `cloth_styles`) VALUES ('socks', '3');

SELECT * FROM clothing WHERE FIND_IN_SET(2, cloth_styles); //only jeans and hat
```

Play with it at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad9e8/1/0

Regarding 2, it is a very bad practice especially when you have large tables and performance is an issue. It does simplify a lot the queries though ....